# phone:WebBrowser handle mail link

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a WebBrowser control:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="ArticleContent" Navigating="ArticleContent_Navigating" Navigated="ArticleContent_Navigated" />
```

And i get article from server like a HTML string:

```
string Article = "<p>Sometext</p><a href=\"mailto:artjomgsd@inbox.lv\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Arial Unicode MS&quot;; mso-fareast-language:LV\">artjomgsd@inbox.lv</span></a>";
```

I do this:

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString(Article);
```

And have this function to stop loading icon:

```
private void ArticleContent_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HideLoading();
}
```

And this function to handle links ( to open links in external browser):

```
private void ArticleContent_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(e.Uri.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
    webBrowserTask.Show();
}
```

**My question is, why when i tap E-mail hyperlink nothing hapens? It even doesn't enter ArticleContent_Navigating() function?**

P.S. I want to open MailTask on clicking on mail hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `mailto:` it not supported by the `WebBrowser` control on Windows Phone.

What you can do is inject Javascript in the HTML that will enumerate all `a` tags and wire up an `onclick` event. That event will call `window.external.Notify` which will in turn raise the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebBrowser`, with the URL as a parameter.

It is a little complicated but I think it's the only option for dealing with the mailto protocol on Windows Phone.

Here is some sample code:

```
// Page Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    browser.ScriptNotify += browser_ScriptNotify;
    browser.Loaded += browser_Loaded;
}

void browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Sample HTML code
    string html = @"<html><head></head><body><a href='mailto:test@test.com'>Send an email</a></body></html>";

    // Script that will call raise the ScriptNotify via window.external.Notify
    string notifyJS = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
                            window.onload = function() {
                                var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                                    links[i].onclick = function() {
                                        window.external.Notify(this.href);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </script>";

    // Inject the Javascript into the head section of the HTML document
    html = html.Replace("<head>", string.Format("<head>{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, notifyJS));

    browser.NavigateToString(html);
}

void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
    {
        string href = e.Value.ToLower();
        if (href.StartsWith("mailto:"))
        {
            EmailComposeTask email =  new EmailComposeTask();
            email.To = href.Replace("mailto:", string.Empty);
            email.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your Html tag just write **Http//**  before mailto:artjomgsd@inbox.lv\ on your link it will work fine

like bellow

```
"<p>Sometext</p><a href=\"http://mailto:artjomgsd@inbox.lv\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Arial Unicode MS&quot;; mso-fareast-language:LV\">artjomgsd@inbox.lv</span></a>";
```

i tested this code in my application now its work..

Comment: That doesn't work, it just redirects the browser to "inbox.lv". The question was about using the mailto: protocol for creating a new email.